# Is there a way to display the amount that is about to be charged to the customer in the payment form?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, global-payments-api

I'm trying to implement the HPP in my .NET webform and so far I was able to set up the server-side code and the client with the provided libraries. However I was wondering if it was possible to display the amount that is charged to the customer when the payment form is presented to them (using the **full page redirect**).

I tried to dig a bit in the available code to find a possible option hidden somewhere but no success.

Comment: I am not familiar with using the Global Payments API but I'm fairly certain we'll need more information to help. For example, what does "HPP" stand for? Where is your code that makes the API call to get data via the API currently? How about your code that handles the redirect of form submit. Are you using the API package for .NET (added via `dotnet add package GlobalPayments.Api`)? Or are you making custom calls to the API without any package?

Comment: @TylerH HPP stands for [Hosted Payment Page](https://developer.globalpay.com/ecommerce/HPP-overview), it's what Global Payments uses for their payment form. I am using the nuget package provided by Global Payments and I'm following the Step by Step guide to implement the solution. The redirect is done via their own JavaScript library that they provided. I only need to feed the JS function with the id of the payment button, the response URL and the json that is built in the server side with the package. The click of the payment button redirects the client to the payment form.